# Limit access to wp-admin but still be able to log in from different locations?

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess

I have problems with some cms attacks, and I uploaded the following .htaccess to wp-admin

```
    # Block access to wp-admin.
order deny,allow
allow from x.x.x.x #studio ip
deny from all
```

Is there a way I could trick the website thinking I come from studio ip x.x.x.x even when I am at different locations (coffee companys, clients)?

Comment: Can you use a VPN?

Comment: @nachito, never tried it. Any tutorial/how to tips?? I think my studio ip address is static.

Comment: There are tons of options. I'd suggest OpenVPN. [Documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) on their website is pretty good